# Hairpins just affect the volume of the next note in Musescore 3.4

Tags: musescore

I faced a problem in Musescore 3.4.2.When I use a hairpin (e.g **diminuendo**) for a note , it only affects the volume of the next untied note (and without any gradient,a solid diminution) and the current note is held intact.By the next untied note here I mean **E4** in the following screenshot but that's not the case here because I've used **Dynamics**.

[image]

And here's the properties in the inspector window :
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is it related to the **SoundFont** I'm using ? BTW I use a different soundfont for **Violoncell**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't explain why no volume gradient is audible in Musescore 3 **.4**, which should support single-note volume gradients, but I must note that your decrescendo has only one note between its beginning and end and therefore may justifiably affect only that middle note (at best) and may not even reach the ending note with "mp" on it (at worst).

Comment: If you switch to the standard soundfont that shipped with the package, does it then do as you wish?   In the mixer, it's "Cello Expr."

Comment: @NevinWilliams Yeah.That only works with the default soundfont.What can I do to achieve the same thing from a custom soundfont?

Comment: @Dekkadeci From the musescore manual : ```By default, a hairpin always affects playback when it spans a series of separate notes. In addition, for instruments supporting single note dynamics (e.g. strings, brass etc.), playback is also enabled across a single note or series of tied notes. (Note: Prior to version 3.1 hairpins only affected playback between notes, not that of single or tied notes.)```.How should an instrument in a soundfont support single note dynamics?

Comment: That's probably something you'll have to ask the folks in a forum at Musescore:

Comment: https://musescore.org/en/forum

Comment: I tried with the built in piano, bass clarinet, and cello, and all "performed" the diminuendo. So it would seem to be the specific sound font you're using.

Comment: @Aaron did you use a new Musescore version? There have been enourmous improvements made in the last year, particularly in the area of playback.

Comment: @leftaroundabout 3.4.2. (I also have v4, but I ran my tests in 3)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering with the hairpin in MuseScore is due to the SoundFont you're using; different SoundFonts can produce various volume changes.

A SoundFont that supports single note dynamics would typically contain samples of each instrument at different dynamic levels. These dynamic levels playback the volume changes across a single note or tied notes.

The SoundFont needs to include separate samples for different dynamic levels. Some SoundFonts may also include additional information, such as velocity mapping or layer switching, to control the dynamic level of the instrument based on the velocity of the note being played.

It would be best if you had a SoundFont that specifically advertises single note dynamics and ensure that it's compatible with MuseScore.